# Pythonic way to serialize static class variables to json

Tags: python, json, deep-learning

I wish to serialize an entire class to json. However, most of the variables I need are static variables (not defined within `__init__()`). Is there a Pythonic way to do that, other then the naive solution, i.e., calling all variables by name?

So far, I tried to call `json.dump()` with an encoder to handle numpy arrays:

```
cfg = MyConfig(Config)

class NumpyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

with open(os.path.join(logs_dir, 'config.json'), 'w') as file:
    json.dump(cfg.__dict__, file, cls = NumpyEncoder)
```

However (of course) this snippet only took care of the three variables that are declared in `__init__()`, and left out the static vars.

More info, just in case:
I want to serialize a class that inherits from `config` in [Mask RCNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did some research and found a solution, just in case someone gets here via Google. The way to save all the class variables, even the static ones, is to call `json.dump()` with the class name, and not the instance name, like so:

```
with open(os.path.join(logs_dir, 'config.json'), 'w') as file:
        json.dump(Config.__dict__.copy(), file, cls = NumpyEncoder)
```

The reason I call `copy()` on `Config.__dict__` is that calling `__dict__` on the class (not instance) returns a `mappingproxy` object, which cannot naively be written to json using `dump()`. Coping the object turns it into a dictionary, which fixed the problem.